# Why did the size of my video file increase after being cropped by FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, android

I use FFmpeg library to crop a video in an Android project.
User captured video with device camera.

- 10-sec video original 640x480 = 200 KB

After crop by FFmpeg; why did the cropped file size is increase?:

- 10-sec video cropped 640x417 = 1.4 MB (!!!)

I used this command:

```
-i video.mp4 -vf crop=640.0:417.10345:0:0 -threads 5 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 videocropped.mp4
```

Details Camera Device for Original Video Capture:

- **File Format:** MP4
- **Video Codec:** H263
- **Audio Codec:** AMR-NB
- **Video Encoded Bitrate:** 256000
- **Frame Rate:** 30 fps
- **Video Dimensions:** 640x480

Comment: You don't specify a target codecs at all...?

Answer (score 0):

The `-preset ultrafast` means a lot less time is spent on compression.  Since you're decompressing the file, cropping, then re-compressing it, you'll end up with a bigger file.

There's no easy way to get the "correct" way to process the file because your source video is already compressed.  The process will require decompression -> crop -> recompression so you'll have to either spend time compressing it or deal with a bigger file.